# splitting data into test and train r studio

Tags: r

Hi I am very new at using R and I am trying to split the data into training and testing. I keep getting the following outputs:

```
> wisc_bc_data_test <- wisc_bc_data_test[-train_ind, ]
Error: object 'wisc_bc_data_test' not found
> wisc_bc_data_test <- wisc_bc_data_test[-train_ind, ]
Error: object 'wisc_bc_data_test' not found
```

I do not know if it is a small error i have made with syntax or I have not set the trains and test up correctly and the following code is below:

```
data_split <- floor(0.7 * nrow(wisc_bc_data))

set.seed(123)

train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(wisc_bc_data)), size = data_split)

wisc_bc_data_train <- wisc_bc_data_train[train_ind, ]

wisc_bc_data_test <- wisc_bc_data_test[-train_ind, ]
```

Comment: Should be `wisc_bc_data_train <- wisc_bc_data[train_ind, ]` and `wisc_bc_data_test <- wisc_bc_data[-train_ind, ]`

Comment: At which point do you declare/read in the `wisc_bc_data` object? It's not clear from your code where you do that. Same goes for `wisc_bc_data_train` and `wisc_bc_data_test`.